# Why is rooting considered dangerous?

Tags: root-access

I understand that being root, applications can do a lot more with your device, but an application first needs root access, so what is the problem? By that logic, Linux as a whole is a dangerous environment since you can give root access to commands by using "sudo". Wouldn't it be more correct to say that root access is as dangerous as the user? If the user is stupid and gives root access to all applications, then yes it is dangerous, but stupidity of users will always be present in the IT. field.

If you know what you give root access to, in what way is rooting your device more dangerous than not rooting?

Comment: root access is as dangerous as the user. thats it. if you talking about vulnerability "user" can also be the attacker. beware on android, apps permissions are based on user permissions - each app is another user. you can not compare with linux

Answer (score -1):

> Why is rooting considered dangerous

Because when you root your phone you have (basically) full access to your phone, if you accidentally delete a system file/application it can [brick your phone](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/what-does-it-mean-to-brick-a-phone) & you have no way to get your files back unless, of course you have the stock firmware downloaded & restore your phone using [Odin](https://odindownload.com/download/).

Comment: What is your affiliation with the site techwalla.com?

Comment: none lol, just a random site i found XP